# Is there support for Devextreme with Vue 3 for typescript?

Tags: typescript, devextreme

I tried to put DevExtreme in my vue 3 project with typescript. I got the error that it has not found the main.js file, this is because in my project is with typescript and should be main.ts. There is no DevExtreme for vue 3 with typescript?
[image]